# textColor defined in style not being applied to button text

Tags: java, android, button, colors, styles

I have a several buttons in my application and I want to apply a style to all of them.

The following is my styles.xml file which I placed in my values folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>

     <style name="buttonStyle">
      <item name="android:textStyle"> bold </item>
      <item name="android:textColor"> #282780 </item>
      <item name="android:textSize"> 20sp </item>
     </style>

</resources>
```

And in my layout xml file I use the style within the button as follows,

```
<Button android:id="@+id/ok_preview_appointment_button" 
        android:text="@string/ok_preview_appointment_button"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```

I get the following error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value ' #282780 ' must start with #"

I checked out other threads but they all seem to encounter this problem when they use @color which is not my case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have given space in the style like: <item name="android:textColor"> #282780 </item>. try after removing. I am not sure but everything else is looking fine so that may be the issue.

Comment: You were actually right! Could you please post your answer separately so that I can mark it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have given space in the style like: 
`<item name="android:textColor"> #282780 </item>`. 
Try after removing it. I am not sure but everything else is looking fine so that may be the issue.